# In the Android API is there a way to obtain the reason a voice connection hasn't been established?

Tags: android, gsm, phone-call

I'd like to know if the reason a voice connection (when making a phone call) hasn't been established is because there was busy tone or because the other side did not answer the call.

Is there API to get this information? If the answer is no then I'd like to know if this information is provided by GSM hardware/drivers at all?

Comment: For the sake of completeness, I take it you did browse the API docs and nothing jumped out?

Answer (score 0):

Even if you could interrogate the detail of the disconnect message (and I don't believe you can with the current Android API's) you would be still be relying on the various switches/protocols/operators in the end to end connection mapping the reasons for the disconnect back accurately, which may not be 100% reliable especially on international calls and older networks.

If you just require an approach that will generally be right, rather than having to be correct 100% of the time, then you may be able to base it simply on the time it takes for the disconnect message to come back - in other words if it takes a long time it is more likely to be because the call timed out waiting for someone to answer.

With the prevalence of voicemail these days you may find that most calls are answered one way or another anyway, depending on the country/network you are interested in (for example Mobiles will generally be more likely to go to voicemail than landlines still).